# problems with appendChild <LI> and having Images match <LI> element

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, appendchild

I would like to have 3 li elements and in those li elements I want 1 image.

All the images go into the first li element instead of being spread out.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated...

I have tried this but it does not work..

/////////////CODE///////////////////

```
var node = document.createElement("LI");

node.innerHTML =
    "<ul class= rsox style=list-style-type: none>" +
    "<li class=images id=imageList>" +
    "</li>" +
    "</ul>";


document.getElementById('sele').appendChild(node);

var image = { image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg };

   for (i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {

    container = document.getElementById ("imageList");



container.innerHTML += "<img class= imageClass src=https://www.WEB-SITE-NAME.com/" + image[i] + ">"
   }
```

Comment: What is `sele`? Can you share enough of your [mcve] code that we can easily recreate your problem and create a valid, practical answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really not clean and I think I know what you want to achieve, so here's my try in fixing your code:

```
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"];

var node = document.createElement("li"};

node.className = "rsox" ;
node.style.listStyleType = "none";

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.className = "images";
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.className = "imageClass";
  img.alt = "";
  img.src = "https://www.WEB-SITE-NAME.com/" + images[i];
  listItem.appendChild(img);
  node.appendChild(listItem);
}

document.getElementById("sele").appendChild(node);
```

I haven't tested this, so if you get any errors or something, tell me.

Comment: Thanks Volper this will work; appending the image to the node and than append it as one package will work I haven’t tried it I had to get to work so I put the code together in 10 mins... Thank you..

Comment: Also, make your code clean because it's easier to read it if you do. I've found so many mistakes in your code... But that's good! Programmers should learn by mistakes, and fixing them is an useful skill.